# How to make BootstrapDialog movable on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog to make a dialog, but on mobile phones the dialog mostly larger than the screen size. On Desktop when I change the width into the same size as mobile, we can drag the dialog header using mouse, but it can't be done on mobile.

This is the screen size.

[image: before dragging]

The dialog after being dragged to left.

[image: after dragging]

Is there a way to make the dialog dragable on mobile?
Or is there a better solution?

**EDIT**

I tried to reproduce the problem using simpler setup, but it shows different css used on `.modal-dialog`:

the problem:

[image: the problematic one]

the simpler setup:

[image: simpler setup]

And now I know that the problem was the CSS' `min-width` property.
Then I hack it by replacing that property when creating `BootstrapDialog`

```
onshown: function() {
  $('.modal-dialog').css('min-width', 'auto');
}
```

Comment: you can find different modal sizes here http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/ look for heading `More dialog sizes` and make the modal responsive or you can check at this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes, it's also supported

Comment: @Kokizzu Post your code for this modal

Comment: i don't know why i could not reproduce the problem with simpler setup -__-)/||

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dialog sizes I think this is answered in comments. For dragging the dialog around [`draggable : true`] on mobiles you must change a little bit in the sourcecode.

bootstrap3-dialog does simply not respond to mobile events such as `touchstart`, `touchend` and `touchmove` <sup>{[**reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)}</sup>.

Take a look at the code from line 1080 :
https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-dialog.js#L1080

Add mobile events so bootstrap3-dialog can be draggable on mobile devices too :

```
...
makeModalDraggable: function() {
    if (this.options.draggable) {
        this.getModalHeader().addClass(this.getNamespace('draggable')).on('mousedown touchstart', {
            dialog: this
        }, function(event) {
            var dialog = event.data.dialog;
            dialog.draggableData.isMouseDown = true;
            var dialogOffset = dialog.getModalDialog().offset();
            dialog.draggableData.mouseOffset = {
                top: event.clientY - dialogOffset.top,
                left: event.clientX - dialogOffset.left
            };
        });
        this.getModal().on('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel', {
            dialog: this
        }, function(event) {
            event.data.dialog.draggableData.isMouseDown = false;
        });
        $('body').on('mousemove touchmove', {
            dialog: this
        }, function(event) {
            var dialog = event.data.dialog;
            if (!dialog.draggableData.isMouseDown) {
                return;
            }
            dialog.getModalDialog().offset({
                top: event.clientY - dialog.draggableData.mouseOffset.top,
                left: event.clientX - dialog.draggableData.mouseOffset.left
            });
        });
    }

    return this;
},
...
```

NB: Completely untested, but I am convinced that this is (the only) way to go.

NB²: The refactor above is only meant as a here-and-now solution. You should [raise the issue](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/issues) on the github project site. I am sure the authors will think it is a great idea to make bootstrap3-dialog mobile ready too.